# Добавить строку в файл

Tags: python, текст

У меня есть файл в которую питон при действии записывает переменную, но каждый раз питон не переходит на новую строчку, а просто стирает первую и пишет на ней, как мне быть?

```
log = open('logging.txt', 'w')
log.write(f"{player} {rang}")
```

Comment: `'w'` -> `'a'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо использовать ключ 'a'

'w' переписывает данные в файле

```
log = open('logging.txt', 'a')
log.write(f"{player}")
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, простите за мою безалаберность(

Comment: вместо `f"{player}"` лучше писать `f"{player}\n"`

Comment: @Kotik_nekot если ответил на ваш вопрос, отметьте его галочкой.

Comment: да я помечу, тут время